# C# - How to get TrustedConnection property from a SqlConnection

Tags: c#, connection-string, trustedconnection

I want to get connection string components from a string containing the conn string.

It is pretty simple to get Database, Sql Instance , Username and Password using a SqlConnectionStringBuilder, like this:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder cb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cString);
this.textBoxUsername.Text = this.UserName = cb.UserID;
this.textBoxPassword.Text = this.Password = cb.Password;
...
```

My problem is that i want to get the TrustedConnection also, and i don't know how to do it.

Having the conn string "Server=Me\SQLEXPRESS;Database=AWEBL; Connection Timeout = 30;" Trusted_Connection=True;" , is it any other way than parsing the cString (connection string) to get the Trusted_Connection property ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set:

```
cb["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
```

get:

```
var trustedConnection = cb["Trusted_Connection"];
```

Comment: that was so simple ... Thanks for the quick answer !:)

Comment: i guess you can add that i would be same as `cb.IntegratedSecurity`